# Gravity Form is not displaying changes

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I was working on a wordpress site and I encountered a strange issue. There is a greavity form. I'm trying to make changes but its not showing any changes on the page where I used the form. But if I preview the form, its showing changes. Can you guys tell me why is it?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a caching plugin is running. Caching plugins have been known to interfere with form performance and function. You'll need to flush the cache. Then test your form again.

Please contact the provider of the caching plugin for advice on excluding Gravity Forms and form submissions from caching.